# Is it correct to use Assert.Fail inside methods call by TestMethods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm planning to use `Assert.Fail` in this way in my unit testing.

1. Inside a private helper method inside the Test class (`IsFileExist`)
2. Inside the methods of a helper class (`LoadData`)

   - So is this ok? or this is out of the unit test framework usage?
   - If I did like this when the Assert.Fail execute does it unwind the whole stack for the test method or just only unwind the stack for that particular method?

**Helper class**

```
public class DataLoader
{
  public void LoadData(string file)
  {
    if (Util.readfile(file)) {
      Assert.Fail("Unable to read the file.");
    }
  }
}
```

**Test class**

```
[TestClass]
public class testFileData
{            
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestData()
    {
      string file = "C:\\data.txt";
      this.IsFileExist(file);

      DataLoader dl = new DataLoader();
      dl.LoadData(file);
    }

    private void IsFileExist(string file)
    {
      if(!Util.IsFileExist(file)) {
        Assert.Fail("File not exist");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grant Winney : yes, only by test methods.  `Util.readfile()` is just a  mock to show my idea to you guys

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `Assert` is in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` name space *should* serve as a hint that no, you should not be using it out side of a unit test.

If you want to fail based on a condition in your code, throw an exception.

Comment: I think the helper is only being used by tests, not production code